# Android app Facebook Sign-In remembers user, but Google Sign In doesn't

Tags: android, facebook, google-signin

So I've implemented Facebook sign-in, now I've implemented Google. It signs in successfully, but when I restart the app, the user has to log in again. If I log in with FB however, it does as it should.
Here's my `AuthListener`:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Log.d("AD", "User is logged in.");
                SignUp.this.startActivity(startMainActivity);
            } else {
                Log.d("AD", "User is not logged in.");
            }
        }
    };
```

And everything else to do with Google Sign In:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "There has been an error connecting to Google: " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

---

```
private void signIn() {
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
```

---

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d("AD", "Signed in via google successfully:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        this.startActivity(startMainActivity);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        Toast.makeText(this, "An error has occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

It's weird; I always have trouble with Google and nothing else :{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. I was missing the `firebaseAuthWithGoogle` method:

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d("AD", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d("AD", "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w("AD", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

And I had to call on it in the overridden `onActivityResult`:

```
if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        }
```